# What does this code do?

Tags: command-line

I've found this code in a tweet:

```
:(){ :|: & };:
```

It said something about fork, but I don't completely get how it works. Could anybody please explain in detail what it does and how it works?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a "fork bomb", as you've heard. There's a whole [wikipedia page about it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb).

> The fork bomb in this case is a recursive function that runs in the
>   background, thanks to the ampersand operator. This ensures that the
>   child process does not die and keeps forking new copies of the
>   function, consuming system resources.
>   -Wikipedia

In short, what it's doing is it's creating more and more processes (by calling the same function recursively) thereby overloading the system.

You'll note that the function identifier is ":()" which you could replace with a name and indent the code to make it more legible:

By replacing the function identifier and re-indenting, the code reads:

```
bomb() { 
  bomb | bomb & 
}; 
bomb
```

*"Don't try this at home kids."* -Mr. Wizard